# Mysql select order by acts like a string, not a number

Tags: php, mysql, numbers, int, sql-order-by

How do you order by number if your number can fall below and be bigger than 0?

Example Mysql table:

```
|Name|Karma|
 __________
|Me  | -8  |
|Bill|  5  |
|Tom |  2  |
|Saly|  0  |
|San.| -3  |
```

Example select query

```
$sql="SELECT karma FROM table ORDER BY karma DESC";
```

The result I get is this (separated by comma): 5,2,0,-8,-3.
Shouldn't it be 5,2,0,-3,-8?
I discovered somewhere in the internet that mysql orders by string. How to make it order by number?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please when asking database questions, always specify what types the columns are.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Karma` will be ordered as a string if you have made it a string, i.e. a `varchar` column.

Convert the column to a `INT`, and it will order numerically.

You also have the option of not changing the table, but casting the column into the right type while sorting:

```
SELECT karma FROM table ORDER BY CAST(karma AS int) DESC
```

but that is bad for performance.

Comment: Hm, I thought varchar will do the trick, BUT I was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: The correct way is to store this value is an INT, not a VARCHAR, used a signed value, that way you can do negatives.  It'll improve your performance plus you can add|substract to the column without your PHP code knowing the value, which is another performance improvement.

Answer (score 14):

There's another weirdest option:

```
SELECT karma FROM table ORDER BY karma+0 DESC
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know mySQL did that. Still, it's an implicit cast and not good for performance.

Comment: @ne5tebio Hackable? You mean from outside? I don't think so. How would that work?

Comment: Is this faster than casting to an INT?